# Querying attributes where value is not yet set

Tags: rally

Any of you guys know how to query rally for a set of things where an string attribute value is currently not yet set?
I can’t query for the value equal to an empty string. That doesn’t parse. And I can’t use “null” either.  Or rather, I can try “null” and it parses fine but it doesn’t result in finding anything.

```
query = @rally_api.find(:defect, :fetch =>true,
                        :project_scope_up => false, :project_scope_down => false,
                        :workspace => @workspace,
                        :project => @project) { equals :integration_i_d, "" }
```

This was followed up by telling the me to substitute "" with nil which didn't work. Null was tried to no success as well. I've tried "null" and null and "". None of them work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with our Ruby REST toolkit but directly hitting our WSAPI, you would say `(<Field> = null)`. Notice that there are no quotes around "null".

Also, I'm wondering if the use of `contains` in your example above is what you wanted. You might want `=`.

Answer (score 0):

try: { equal :integration_i_d, '""' }

Also, if rally_rest_api seems slow - we're working on something faster here:
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/ruby-rally-api